# Adding Fade in & Fade Out on refresh

Tags: javascript

I Don't really know how to write JS

I have this code which i use to cycle 2 pages, I was trying to add a fade-in/out effect on refresh.

Basically what i mean is that i want to have a fade-in/out effect every time the i frame refreshes, and i have no clue on how to do it.

I am new to this Please Help.

Thanks!!!

Code:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
#container{
    width:1900px;
    height:1080px;
    border:0px solid #000; 
    overflow:hidden;
    margin:auto;
}
#container iframe {
    width:1920px;
    height:1180px;
    margin-bottom:-100px;
    margin-top:-30px;   
    border:0 solid;
 }
-->
</style>
<div id="container">
<iframe id="if_one" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var pages = [
    'Page 1',
    'Page 2'
], p = pages.length;
while(--p > -1){
    (function(p){
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = pages[p];
        pages[p] = a;
    })(p);
}

function loadIframe() {
var page = pages[(p = ++p % pages.length)], bust = 'bustcache=' + new Date().getTime();
page = page.search? page.href + '&' + bust : page.href + '?' + bust;
document.getElementById('if_one').src = page;

setTimeout(loadIframe, 15000);
}
loadIframe();
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly do you want to fade in and out, the text of a A tag?

Comment: seems more like a CSS animation question than javascript. Personally i would probably not use an iFrame but depending on situation iFrames are not pure evil :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34645518/4746328

Comment: Basically what i meant was that i want to have a fade-in/out effect every time the <i frame> refreshes, and i have no clue on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is using some jQuery.
For the purpose of illustration I am loading the `html()` function but you could make ajax calls if you wanted instead by using [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

I am making some assumptions here.

- that you want your webpage to alternate between one page and another
- you want it to reload at some interval in my example this is 3000ms or 3 seconds i think you wanted it to be 15 sec

```js
pages = ['https://google.com', 'page2', 'page3','...pageN'];
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').html(pages[0]);
  clearInterval();
  count = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    if(count==pages.length){
      count=0;
    }
    $('.item').html(pages[count]).animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, 700)
    count ++;
  }, 3000)




})
```

```css
.item {
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadein {
  opacity: 0;
}
.fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">item
  </div>
</div>
```